# Borderlands Rack Hive

Tags: borderlands

I'm having problem killing the Rack Hive on the Trash Coast. I get killed by all the Rack's it spawns.

lvl 30 Hunter

Does anyone have a good strategy? I already know that I should aim for the eyes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right where you enter the arena for that battle, there's a cliff on the left hand side going up. If you look down from it you should see the tents and ammo crates to the right.

From this ledge you can easily snipe the Hive's eyes (revolvers are faster in my opinion though...spam works). Use a SMG or shotgun for the swooping rakks.

Use your action skill for health!! There's a skill that lets your bloodwing steal health for you and another that increases the number of enemies that it can attack. The combination helps against the waves of rakk and the acid balls that the Hive shoot at you. Just throw the bloodwing out whenever there are rakk and you'll be ok.

Good luck!

Comment: Respeccing to rouge helped a lot.

Comment: glad that I helped! :D

Answer (score 4):

Aim for the eyes, make sure you're using a corrosive weapon, and SMG is best for him. Use a shotgun against the Raks he spawns.  You can hide on the upper part and take out the raks when they fly out, and then focus on him again after.